# How to list all files in folders and sub-folders using scandir and display them as an option in select?

Tags: php, web, web-development-server

I have a piece of code that I would like to modify to list all files in folders and sub-folders in the current path. I have found several possible solutions. I tried to implement them actually, but nothing seemed to work so I am not sure if they are actually working or not or it was just me implemented them wrong. Either way this is my current code:

```
<?php 
        $currentdir = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/test/'; //change to your directory
        $dir = opendir($currentdir);
        echo '<select name="workout">';
            $file = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($dir));
            while($file = readdir($dir))
            {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                    echo "<option value='$file'>$file</option>";
            }           
                else {
                    continue;
            }
        }
        echo '</select>';
        closedir($dir); 
?>
```

Currently this code shows results:

```
$currentdir
   Option1
   Option2
   Option3
   SUB-FOLDER1
   SUB-FOLDER2
```

Can someone help me and show me how to write/rewrite the code using existing one to display files from folders and other sub-folders to look something like this:

```
$currentdir
  Option1
  Option2
  Option3
    SUB-FOLDER1
      Option1
      Option2
      Option3
    SUB-FOLDER2
      Option1
      Option2
      Option3
```

I became really desperate for a solution and thank you all in advance.

Comment: I think your problem is that PHP is not going to use the C:\ as a place to look.  It's running on a server, after all.  It's not going to see a local filesystem.  It should just use the relative path from your site's root.

Comment: If you want to check if a file is a directory, there's a function for that. Did you look it up?

Comment: I am running local server so it is able show the files and folders in current path but not the sub-folders and files in it.
@Aleatoric
I did found code for that using foreach but I, as stated in my question, probably didn't implemented well in my code. So, how can I inlcude that part in the code I have to look if the file is a directory?

Comment: you should consider using 'C:/xampp/htdocs/test/' instead.

Comment: Thank you @AndrasGyomrey I have modified the code as you suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the other answers are fine and correct, allow me to add my solution as well:

```
function dirToOptions($path = __DIR__, $level = 0) {
    $items = scandir($path);
    foreach($items as $item) {
        // ignore items strating with a dot (= hidden or nav)
        if (strpos($item, '.') === 0) {
            continue;
        }

        $fullPath = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item;
        // add some whitespace to better mimic the file structure
        $item = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $level * 3) . $item;
        // file
        if (is_file($fullPath)) {
            echo "<option>$item</option>";
        }
        // dir
        else if (is_dir($fullPath)) {
            // immediatly close the optgroup to prevent (invalid) nested optgroups
            echo "<optgroup label='$item'></optgroup>";
            // recursive call to self to add the subitems
            dirToOptions($fullPath, $level + 1);
        }
    }

}

echo '<select>';
dirToOptions();
echo '</select>';
```

It uses a [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) call to fetch the subitems. Note that I added some whitespace before each item to better mimic the file structure. Also I closed the `optgroup` immediatly, to prevent ending up with nested `optgroup` elements, which is invalid HTML.

Comment: I have another question and I believe it is a small adjustment. On the line where you output `<option>` I have added value of the `$path` because I will need to output that info in the new file when submit the form. When I do submit the form, and output value of that option it shows the full path `C:/xampp/htdocs/test/` and then the item I selected; sth like this: `C:/xampp/htdocs/test/sub-folder/SelectedOption`. Now, what is the best way to trim it down so the output of the option value shows only sub-folders and file without full path; sth like this: `sub-folder/SelectedOption`? Thank you!

Comment: EDIT: I meant `$fullpath` and not `$path`

Answer (score 1):

Find all the files and folders under a specified directory.

```
function scanDirAndSubdir($dir, &$out = []) {
    $sun = scandir($dir);

    foreach ($sun as $a => $filename) {
        $way = realpath($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
        if (!is_dir($way)) {
            $out[] = $way;
        } else if ($filename != "." && $filename != "..") {
            scanDirAndSubdir($way, $out);
            $out[] = $way;
        }
    }

    return $out;
}

var_dump(scanDirAndSubdir('C:/xampp/htdocs/test/'));
```

### Sample :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'C:/xampp/htdocs/test/text1.txt' (length=30)
  1 => string 'C:/xampp/htdocs/test/text1.txt' (length=30)
  2 => string 'C:/xampp/htdocs/test/subfolder1/text8.txt' (length=41)
  3 => string 'C:/xampp/htdocs/test/subfolder4/text9.txt' (length=41)
```

Comment: Your function is similar to another one I used. You forgot to change "getDirRecursive", so your function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DirectoryIterator` for looking into folder here is my approch

```
$di = new DirectoryIterator("/dir");
foreach($di as $dir){
    if ($dir->isDot()) continue;
    echo "<option value='", $dir->getFilename(), "'>", $dir->getFilename(), "</option>";
}
```

anyway for looking into sub directories as well

```
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($ri as $dir){
    if ($dir->isDot()) continue;
    echo "<option value='", $dir->getFilename(), "'>", $dir->getFilename(), "</option>";
}
```

Comment: Check your syntax highlighting; something's not right here.

Comment: If I understood it right. I should replace my code completely with yours except leaving '$currentdir' in the first line? if yes, then I am receiving the following error: **Fatal error: Call to undefined method SplFileInfo::isDot() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 29**. What am i doing wrong? Just to mention that I replaced $path with $currentdir, right? 

It also told me that there's an extra **"** in the last line, so I removed it and "'>" became '>"

Comment: replace the `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST` flag with `FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME | FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_SELF`

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use above statement then this another alternative:

```
    <?php
function listdir($currentdir){
    $dir = opendir($currentdir);
    $file = readdir($dir);
    echo "<optgroup label='$currentdir'>";
    do {
        if (is_dir($currentdir."/".$file) && $file != "." && $file != ".."){
            listdir($currentdir."/".$file);
            echo $currentdir."/".$file;
        } else if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            echo "<option value='$file'>$file</option>";
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    } while($file = readdir($dir));
    echo "</optgroup>";
    closedir($dir); 
}
echo '<select name="workout">';
listdir('/var/www'); //change to your directory
echo '</select>';
?>
```